# default values on a related model

Tags: odoo-14

From my model I have a many2one relationship to `res.partner`

Such relationship "feeds" a dropdown field (menu)

Such dropdown field contains a list of partners and the last item is "Start writing", to create a new partner (see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXE8p.jpg) picture; "Inizia a scrivere is the Italian for "Start writing")

I'd like the new partner being created to have some fields automatically assigned with some default values

I've been suggested to use an action with a context but in this case I'm not starting the creation of a new partner from a menu or button and I'm not sure how to call my action from the last item of the dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

you can apply a context attribute on a related field in a view

Like this

```
<field name="some_related_field_id"
             context="{'default_field_to_be_set_on_the_related_model': 'some_value'}"/>
```

Please notice that the name of the field to be set is not

```
default_field_to_be_set_on_the_related_model
```

it is

```
field_to_be_set_on_the_related_model
```

The initial `default_` is a convention to set default values

That's required, if you don't prefix the name of your field with `default_` the thing won't work